# Replying with SSML for Phone Gateway

Tags: dialogflow-cx

As part of my response JSON, I am sending the following to the Dialogflow CX Phone Gateway:

```
    "fulfillmentResponse": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "outputAudioText": {
                    "ssml": "<speak>That is <break time=\"500ms\"/> <emphasis level=\"strong\">correct</emphasis></speak>",
                    "allowPlaybackInterruption": true
                }
            },
            {
                "outputAudioText": {
                    "ssml": "<speak>What would you like to do now?</speak>",
                    "allowPlaybackInterruption": true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

If I understand the documentation for [ResponseMessage](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/Fulfillment#ResponseMessage) correctly, then these should be used for audio output.

But if the [OutputAudioText](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/Fulfillment#OutputAudioText) object are the only messages included, then nothing is said in response. If I then add a [Text](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/Text) object, then the (plain) text object is used for TTS.

Is SSML actually supported for the Dialogflow CX Phone Gateway? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known bug at the moment.

See the thread [on twitter](https://twitter.com/afirstenberg/status/1431602928859615234) which is partially excerpted below.

From Lee Boonstra: I tested this, and I can reproduce. I wouldn't be surprised if this is a bug since the telephony gateway is still in early preview and the output audio text seems to be a new feature. - I am checking it with the team.

[image: From Lee Boonstra: I tested this, and I can reproduce. I wouldn't be surprised if this is a bug since the telephony gateway is still in early preview and the output audio text seems to be a new feature. - I am checking it with the team.]

From Lee Boonstra: Yes, I can confirm myself :) - the bug was already filed. Will be fixed very soon, but for the competition you will likely not been able to use SSML in the phone gateway. (It depends per integration tho)

[image: From Lee Boonstra: Yes, I can confirm myself :) - the bug was already filed. Will be fixed very soon, but for the competition you will likely not been able to use SSML in the phone gateway. (It depends per integration tho)]

From Allen "Prisoner" Firstenberg: Thanks for checking on and confirming this, Lee! Very much appreciated. To make sure I'm on the right track, "outputAudioText" is the correct way to do this?

[image: From Allen "Prisoner" Firstenberg: Thanks for checking on and confirming this, Lee! Very much appreciated. To make sure I'm on the right track, "outputAudioText" is the correct way to do this?]

From Lee Boonstra: Yes it is, and it takes a string with `<speak>` tags

[image: From Lee Boonstra: Yes it is, and it takes a string with tags]